# modules contract by interface, diagram, logic, general informations

Tags: model-view-controller, interface, module, components, diagram

Here is my question, I hope that I'll write it correctly because it is a precise question.

I wonder how to use the interfaces as a contract between two modules. When I draw the module diagrams I never knows which of the modules as the circle and which has the half-open circle. A clear way on how to make the distinction would be very appreciated!

I don't want an example on how to use an interface because I know the properties of the interfaces (behaviors, etc).

Let's say that I got 2 modules, one contains the Bussiness logic, so I'll call it "Model", the other contains the GUI so I'll call it "View".

The view needs a Treeview and a Matrix on each nodes. So we got a tree-like hierarchie that the Model knows about, and for each node we want to fill a matrix of values.

```
root
- node1
-- leaf1
-- leaf2
- node2
- node3
-- leaf3
-- leaf4
```

My guts are telling me that I should do something like this:

```
interface IModelHierarchicMatrix {
    void setTreeViewValues(TreeViewModel treeview);
    void getMatrixValues();
    void setMatrixValues(int[] values);
}

class Model implements IModelHierarchicMatrix {
    // the code where I override the interface's function
}
```

So nice, we can call the needed function for the GUI at the Model. But how can we tell the GUI's class that we need that kind of behaviors (class, etc)...
I find myself often doing this kind of thing:

```
interface IModelHierarchicMatrixGlue {
    void acceptModel(IModelHierarchicMatrix model);
}

class Gui implements IModelHierarchicMatrixGlue {
    private IModelHierarchicMatrix model;

    ...

    @Override
    public void acceptModel(IModelHierarchicMatrix model) {
        if (this.model == null) {
            this.model = model;
        }
    }
}
```

But I always wonder if it's a good way of creating the contract between the Model and the View.
If I got to create a bi-directional contract between the Modules, how should I do that? Because it might create a cyclic logic between the interfaces...

I hope my question was clear enough, thanks in advance.

Comment: Traditional MVC allows the View to interact with the Model for information gathering only, The Controller would mediate action on the model. The model can not interact with the View at any time. (No bi-directional contracts)

Comment: "circle and which has the half-open circle" - I can only guess your talking of a Client-Server representation.

"interface IModelHierarchicMatrix {
    void setTreeViewValues(TreeViewModel treeview);"

Remember the Model and view are -complete- objects. Your Model would never have a "TreeView", The View would contain everything needed for the View objects.